# R: calculate the number of occurrences of a specific event in a specified time future

Tags: r, date, dplyr, aggregate

my simplified data looks like this:

```
set.seed(1453); x = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
date = c('2016-01-01', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-07',  '2016-01-12',  '2016-01-16',  '2016-01-20',
             '2016-01-20',  '2016-01-25',  '2016-01-26',  '2016-01-31')


df = data.frame(x, date = as.Date(date))


df 
x       date
1 2016-01-01
0 2016-01-05
1 2016-01-07
0 2016-01-12
0 2016-01-16
1 2016-01-20
1 2016-01-20
0 2016-01-25
0 2016-01-26
1 2016-01-31
```

I'd like to calculate the number of occurrences for `x == 1` within a specified time period, e.g. 14 and 30 days from the current date (but excluding the current entry, if it is `x == 1`. The desired output would look like this:

```
solution
x       date x_plus14 x_plus30
1 2016-01-01        1        3
0 2016-01-05        1        4
1 2016-01-07        2        3
0 2016-01-12        2        3
0 2016-01-16        2        3
1 2016-01-20        2        2
1 2016-01-20        1        1
0 2016-01-25        1        1
0 2016-01-26        1        1
1 2016-01-31        0        0
```

Ideally, I'd like this to be in `dplyr`, but it is not a must. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Two things. 1) Try not to name objects after functions (sample is also a function). 2) It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: do you need today + 14 observations (rows) or today + 14 days? the latter is much more complicated.

Comment: is your output correct? bcoz `x_plus14[1]` should be `2`

Comment: Not sure where is `as_date` from but you could simply do `sample = data.frame(x, date = as.Date(date))` while both avoiding a dependency and converting to matrix and back using `cbind`

Comment: thanks all for useful comments. @Sotos: now I've changed df names

Comment: @Noobie: + it's 14 days, as specified

Comment: @David Arenburg: thanks, I changed the date part now

Comment: As I said, don't use `cbind` as it converts everything back to a matrix. Why coudn't you just copy/paste my line?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: done!

Comment: Your copy/paste skills need some improvement....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another approach based on `findInterval`:

```
cs = cumsum(df$x) # cumulative number of occurences
data.frame(df, 
           plus14 = cs[findInterval(df$date + 14, df$date, left.open = TRUE)] - cs, 
           plus30 = cs[findInterval(df$date + 30, df$date, left.open = TRUE)] - cs)
#   x       date plus14 plus30
#1  1 2016-01-01      1      3
#2  0 2016-01-05      1      4
#3  1 2016-01-07      2      3
#4  0 2016-01-12      2      3
#5  0 2016-01-16      2      3
#6  1 2016-01-20      2      2
#7  1 2016-01-20      1      1
#8  0 2016-01-25      1      1
#9  0 2016-01-26      1      1
#10 1 2016-01-31      0      0
```

Comment: thanks, @alexis_laz for your answer and help (again)! I really like how simple and elegant it is and it is based on base R. Thanks a million!

Comment: @KasiaKulma : You're welcome. `findInterval` is, indeed, handy on such situtations and it, also, avoids comparing all dates with all dates to return the number of entries `<` from a specific date. Have a nice day!

Comment: This is really elegant!

Answer (score 4):

Earlier I wasn't including the present date and so numbers didn't match.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=`(x14 = sum(df$x[between(df$date, date, date + 14, incbounds = FALSE)]), 
                 x30 = sum(df$x[between(df$date, date, date + 30, incbounds = FALSE)])),
              by = date]

#     x       date x14 x30
#  1: 1 2016-01-01   1   3
#  2: 0 2016-01-05   1   4
#  3: 1 2016-01-07   2   3
#  4: 0 2016-01-12   2   3
#  5: 0 2016-01-16   2   3
#  6: 1 2016-01-20   1   1
#  7: 1 2016-01-20   1   1
#  8: 0 2016-01-25   1   1
#  9: 0 2016-01-26   1   1
# 10: 1 2016-01-31   0   0
```

Or a general solution that will work for any desired range

```
vec <- c(14, 30) # Specify desired ranges
setDT(df)[, paste0("x", vec) := 
            lapply(vec, function(i) sum(df$x[between(df$date, 
                                                     date, 
                                                     date + i, 
                                                     incbounds = FALSE)])),
            by = date]
```

Comment: got the issue!! I was including the present date. Just have `date+1` instead of `date` in `between()`

Comment: @KasiaKulma need to clarify on whether to include the current date or not though she has mentioned in the question. Because the number didn't match for the first row

Comment: thanks for that; and yes, now I edited the post so that it clarifies that the current occurrence, if it is `x==1' should not be included in the calculation. I would not mess with dates, though, as in my original dataset you can find multiple occurrences with the same date, so I can always extract 1 if the solution includes the current record

Comment: In order to get the desired result in both lines just specify `incbounds = FALSE` and leave the original ranges, for instance `between(sample$date, date, date+30, incbounds = FALSE)` (this will have 3 instead of 4 in the first line)

Comment: I'm afraid this gives me inconsistent results: expected_output for entries `x==1` and expected_output - 1 for entries where `x == 0`

Comment: @KasiaKulma  I haven't yet updated my answer based on the edit you made.. Right now no access to RStudio. Shall let you know. Sorry

Comment: @KasiaKulma I just think you need to have `date+x` instead of `date+1` to accomodate your change

Comment: @KasiaKulma See edit, that should match your desired output

Comment: @DavidArenburg, @joel.wilson: thanks a lot for including a more universal solution. I'd like to test it on a different dataset  with a similar structure to the one in my example, but including multiple users. I don't know `data.table`. How could use your solution with `dplyr`'s equivalent of `group_by(user_id)`? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

A concise `dplyr` and `purrr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample %>% 
  mutate(x_plus14 = map(date, ~sum(x == 1 & between(date, . + 1, . + 14))),
         x_plus30 = map(date, ~sum(x == 1 & between(date, . + 1, . + 30))))
```

> ```
>    x       date x_plus14 x_plus30
> 1  1 2016-01-01        1        4
> 2  0 2016-01-05        1        4
> 3  1 2016-01-07        2        3
> 4  0 2016-01-12        2        3
> 5  0 2016-01-16        2        3
> 6  1 2016-01-20        1        1
> 7  1 2016-01-20        1        1
> 8  0 2016-01-25        1        1
> 9  0 2016-01-26        1        1
> 10 1 2016-01-31        0        0
> ```

Comment: thanks, @Axeman, for that, I really like clarity and compactness of your solution. However, I don't understand why your (and other) solution gives `x_plus14 == 1` and gives `x_plus30 == 1` at row 6, as from then to the end of the month there are 2 `x == 1` occurrences (excluding the current one). It's even more surprising that all the other instances have been calculated correctly!

Comment: It's because of the duplicate dates in rows 6 and 7. You can use `between(sample$date, ., . + 14)` but then the dates themselves will also be included, and we end up with 3.

Comment: that's fine, I can always extract 1 from it. If you edit your answer this way, I'll happily accept it

Comment: I realised this approach gives me inconsistent results, depending wether the entry is `x==1` or `x==0'. Any ideas how to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab at it with some `dplyr`+`purrr` help. I got slightly different counts due to the `<=` and `>=` in the helper function `x_next()` if you adjust them properly i think you should be able to get what you want. hth.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("lubridate")
set.seed(1453)

x = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
dates = c('2016-01-01', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-07',  '2016-01-12',  '2016-01-16',  '2016-01-20',
         '2016-01-20',  '2016-01-25',  '2016-01-26',  '2016-01-31')

df = data_frame(x = x, dates = lubridate::as_date(dates))

# helper function to calculate the sum of xs in the next days_in_future
x_next <- function(d, days_in_future) {

  df %>% 
    # subset on days of interest
    filter(dates > d & dates <= d + days(days_in_future)) %>% 
    # sum up xs
    summarise(sum = sum(x)) %>% 
    # have to unlist them so that the (following) call to mutate works
    unlist(use.names=F)
  }

# mutate your df
df %>% 
  mutate(xplus14 = map(dates, x_next, 14),
         xplus30 = map(dates, x_next, 30))
```

Comment: I don't think you are taking into account that `x` should be 1. Also, you should be using `map_dbl`.

Comment: hey @Axeman, don't understand why the downvote...i am taking what you said into account - `sum(x)` will obviously sum over all `x=1` only. using `map_dbl` is _a_ choice but in this case not a wrong one...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `sum(x)`. But you are still getting counts that are too high?

Comment: no worries but there's no way to undo a downvote right?as for the results - i will edit my answer with a strict inequality on the right side and i think it should be correct. note that the original question has a mistake in the example output (row 1 for `x_plus14` is actually 2 if you look at the data).

Comment: update: just re-read all the comments and the desired solution seems to _exclude_ the current date. i updated my answer and now i get the same results as your proposal. imo (and its just a matter of taste) - extracting the anonymous function separately lets you re-use it more often without copy-pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

As other already mentioned, it is strange that you do not count the day from and you should avoid naming objects by names of functions (sample). However, the code bellow reproduce your desired output:

```
set.seed(1453); 
x = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
date = c('2016-01-01', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-07',  '2016-01-12',  '2016-01-16',  '2016-01-20',
             '2016-01-20',  '2016-01-25',  '2016-01-26',  '2016-01-31')


sample = data.frame(x = x, date = as.Date(sample$date))

getOccurences <- function(one_row, sample_data, date_range){
  one_date <- as.Date(one_row[2])
  sum(sample$x[sample_data$date > one_date & 
               sample_data$date < one_date + date_range])
}

sample$x_plus14 <- apply(sample,1,getOccurences, sample, 14)
sample$x_plus30 <- apply(sample,1,getOccurences, sample, 30)

sample

   x       date x_plus14 x_plus30
1  1 2016-01-01        1        3
2  0 2016-01-05        1        4
3  1 2016-01-07        2        3
4  0 2016-01-12        2        3
5  0 2016-01-16        2        3
6  1 2016-01-20        1        1
7  1 2016-01-20        1        1
8  0 2016-01-25        1        1
9  0 2016-01-26        1        1
10 1 2016-01-31        0        0
```